# I can't get the elements in ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, data-retrieval

Here My code for select values in Array-list Named Test i need to get values in Array-List Based on a Button Press Event But it shows Error given below

```
bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            d4 = ex.getText().toString();
            int i=test.size();
           for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) {
               String s= test.get(j).toString();
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }

        }
    });
```

Error Message Is given below

```
 04-04 16:38:29.551 28723-28723/com.example.web03.bulkmessenger E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null
 04-04 16:38:29.551 28723-28723/com.example.web03.bulkmessenger E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@3e5f9413
 04-04 16:38:32.051 28723-28723/com.example.web03.bulkmessenger E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.web03.bulkmessenger, PID: 28723
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
 at com.example.web03.bulkmessenger.MessengerActivity$3.onClick(MessengerActivity.java:127)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5246)
 at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10573)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21256)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

thanks for help in advance

Comment: did you get value here `test.size();`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : yes

Comment: what about `for(int j=0;j<i;j++) {`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya: thanks itz worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IndexOutOfBoundsException because you called array size +1  ..so remove j<=i in for loop.

```
    int i=test.size();         // array size (i.e 10)

     for(int j=0;j<i;j++) {   //j<=i is wrong  because it execute 11th time.so remove =

           String s= test.get(j).toString();  //test.get(11) 
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the IndexOutOfBoundsException error because you've set the variable j in the for loop to "j<=i" try setting it to this

```
bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        d4 = ex.getText().toString();
        int i=test.size();
       for(int j=0;j<i;j++) {
           String s= test.get(j).toString();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your **for loop** to

```
 for(int j=0;j<test.size();j++)
```

Because indexes starts from **0**, but `size()` method returns us length of list.
So if you run for loop until `j <= test.size()` you will exceed the index of your list

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2

**[IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html)** Thrown when a program attempts to access a value in an indexable collection using a value which is outside of the range of valid indices.

**Problem**

```
 for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) { // == Usually any negative integer less than or equal to -1 and positive integer greater than or equal to the size of the object is an index which would be out of bounds.
```

**Solutions**

```
 for(int j=0;j<i;j++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The array goes out of bounds during the last iteration of your for-loop, since your value of `i` is `test.size();` If you just wanted to show a toast using the value iteratively, just use the for-each loop.